# Adobe illustrator linked file name to a layer name script

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want the layer [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7j3X.png)
to have the name of the linked file without .eps at the end.

Comment: So rename the layer... What is the problem?

Comment: there are 400 layers.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I found an answer. So for anyone looking here it is, although it does take to click on every layer, at least you don't have to type it.

```
function test() {
    var sel_itemPlaced = app.activeDocument.selection[0]; // be sure that a linked item (and not an embedded) is selected
    var fileName = sel_itemPlaced.file.name;
    var textContents = fileName.replace(/\%20/g, " "); //change %20 to spaces
    textContents = textContents.replace(/\.[^\.]*$/, ""); //remove extension
    var _item = sel_itemPlaced;
    while (_item.parent.typename != 'Layer') {
        _item = _item.parent;
    }
    _item.parent.name = textContents;
}
test();
```

Comment: oh, and in case you want to sort it by name here is this

Comment: Consider [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66771606/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Answer (score 0):

It does work for all placed images and all layers at once:

```
var images = app.activeDocument.placedItems;

for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++)
    images[i].layer.name = images[i].file.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, "");
```